# How to mount a shared folder as disk with `rwxr-xr-x` permissions?

Tags: macos, sharing, permission, mount, afp

I shared a folder from the host system (OSX) and use mount it in the guest system (OSX). But it is mounted only with `rwx------` mode. I granted an **rw** access for the shared folder for a user in the guest system **and for everyone as read-only**. But in the guest system the folder is going mounted to the /Volumes/ as a shared disk with `rwx------` permissions. How can I mount it with `rwxr-xr-x` permissions?

## Update 1:

in the host system it has `rwxr-xr-x+` permissions

## Update 2:

the problem sounds to be like here: [permissions for mounted internal disk [ask ubuntu]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253305/most-suitable-permissions-for-mounted-internal-disk-shared-with-windows). So is it kind of related to `fmask`, `dmask` (`umask`)?

## Update 3:

here is similar situation, but on linux [700 instead of 755 permissions on auto-mounted USB HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237776/700-instead-of-755-permissions-on-auto-mounted-usb-hdd). so there is a /etc/fstab.hd file on osx but it considered be useless

## Update 4:

it looks like all AFP shares appears as `drwx------`. **How to change it?**

Comment: Please, take a look at chmod. From the "Terminal" prompt, type "man chmod".

Comment: :) already tryed. from host system it is already 755 (`rwxr-xr-x+`), from guest system it doesn't work - insufficient permissions (remount doesn't work, or I don't know all tha options).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the permissions when executing `mount` - the local file permissions or the permissions you set with `chmod` on the directory to which you mount your share will not be taken into consideration.

You should do `mount -t <fs_type> -o m=755 /path/to/source /destination`

I'm not sure which filesystem type is what you're trying to mount (is it nfs? or hfs?) - you only refer to a host system and a guest system without any more details. You'll need to specify the correct file system type to the mount command (but I'm presuming you have already done that and it did work). Also, it would be a good idea for you to read the man for the relevant mount command (so, if the fstype is hfs, you'll need to read `man mount_hfs`; similarly, if it's nfs, you need to `man mount_nfs`; have a look at the bottom of `man mount` for more fs specific mount commands).

Hope that helps!

Comment: It says `-o m: option not supported`

Comment: OK, but can you provide more details? Did you run `mount`, `mount_nfs` or `mount_hfs`? which file system type are you trying to mount? Can you paste the exact command you're trying to execute? `mount_hfs` also has a `-m` option, which you could try to use too: `mount -m 755` should give you the 755 permissions.

Comment: `mount`, as you proposed

Comment: OK, I really need you to copy and paste the exact command you're trying to type into the terminal. Also, please include the exact version of the OSX you're running. As you can see above in my comment, I've asked you a number of questions, but you're only giving minimal information in response.

Comment: The OP mentioned that "all AFP shares appears as drwx------". So it's about `mount_afp`. Unfortunately, I get: `mount_afp: illegal option -- m`. So it looks like mount_afp doesn't support this.

Comment: You can try using the following: `mount -t afp -m=755 afp://path/to/source /path/to/destination` or `mount -t afp -o -m=755 afp://path/to/source /path/to/destination` and see if one of those is supported.

Comment: there is no `-m` option for macOS `mount`, stop referring to `-m`

Comment: no, there isn't a `-m` option. There IS however a `-o m=` option in macOS, or at least there used to be at the time, if I remember correctly